# SVG rotated and flipped text doesn't produce an accurate result

Tags: svg, text, rotation

I would like to write text on SVG at different angles and flip (if angle is  > 90 and < 270 degrees to get text oriented for better readable).

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 800 800" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" > 
<circle  cx="323" cy="422" r="153" fill="none" stroke="#900"  stroke-width="0.38"/>
<circle  cx="323" cy="422" r="228" fill="none" stroke="#900"  stroke-width="0.38"/>
  <g id="E.3011.40-debug" class="units" font-size="10.0" fill="#000"> 
    <line title="0" x1="323" y1="422" x2="477" y2="422" stroke="#900" stroke-width="0.38"></line>
    <text x="477" y="422" style="">way +1 0° 0° </text>
    
    <line title="15" x1="323" y1="422" x2="472" y2="462" stroke="#900" stroke-width="0.38"></line>
    <text x="472" y="462" style="transform-box:fill-box;rotate:15deg;">way +1 0° 15° </text>
    
    <line title="30" x1="323" y1="422" x2="456" y2="499" stroke="#900" stroke-width="0.38"></line>
    <text x="456" y="499" style="transform-box:fill-box;rotate:30deg;">way +1 0° 30° </text>
    
    <line title="45" x1="323" y1="422" x2="432" y2="531" stroke="#900" stroke-width="0.38"></line>
    <text x="432" y="531" style="transform-box:fill-box;rotate:45deg;">way +1 0° 45° </text>
    
    <line title="60" x1="323" y1="422" x2="400" y2="555" stroke="#900" stroke-width="0.38"></line>
    <text x="400" y="555" style="transform-box:fill-box;rotate:60deg;">way +1 0° 60° </text>
    
    <line title="75" x1="323" y1="422" x2="363" y2="571" stroke="#900" stroke-width="0.38"></line>
    <text x="363" y="571" style="transform-box:fill-box;rotate:75deg;">way +1 0° 75° </text>
    
    <line title="90" x1="323" y1="422" x2="323" y2="576" stroke="#900" stroke-width="0.38"></line>
    <text x="323" y="576" style="transform-box:fill-box;rotate:90deg;">way +1 0° 90° </text>
    
    <line title="105" x1="323" y1="422" x2="283" y2="571" stroke="#900" stroke-width="0.38"></line>
    <text x="283" y="571" style="transform-box:fill-box;rotate:105deg;">way +1 0° 105° </text>
    
    <line title="120" x1="323" y1="422" x2="246" y2="555" stroke="#900" stroke-width="0.38"></line>
    <text x="246" y="555" style="transform-box:fill-box;rotate:120deg;">way +1 0° 120° </text>
    
    <line title="135" x1="323" y1="422" x2="215" y2="531" stroke="#900" stroke-width="0.38"></line>
    <text x="215" y="531" style="transform-box:fill-box;rotate:135deg;">way +1 0° 135° </text>
    
    <line title="150" x1="323" y1="422" x2="190" y2="499" stroke="#900" stroke-width="0.38"></line>
    <text x="190" y="499" style="transform-box:fill-box;rotate:150deg;">way +1 0° 150° </text>
    
    <line title="165" x1="323" y1="422" x2="175" y2="462" stroke="#900" stroke-width="0.38"></line>
    <text x="175" y="462" style="transform-box:fill-box;rotate:165deg;">way +1 0° 165° </text>
    
    <line title="180" x1="323" y1="422" x2="170" y2="422" stroke="#900" stroke-width="0.38"></line>
    <text x="170" y="422" style="transform-box:fill-box;rotate:180deg;">way +1 0° 180° </text>
    
    <line title="195" x1="323" y1="422" x2="175" y2="383" stroke="#900" stroke-width="0.38"></line>
    <text x="175" y="383" style="transform-box:fill-box;rotate:195deg;">way +1 0° 195° </text>
    
    <line title="210" x1="323" y1="422" x2="190" y2="346" stroke="#900" stroke-width="1"></line>
    <text x="190" y="346" style="transform-box:fill-box;rotate:210deg;transform:scale(-1,-1);">way +1 0° 210° </text>
    
    <line title="225" x1="323" y1="422" x2="215" y2="314" stroke="#900" stroke-width="0.38"></line>
    <text x="215" y="314" style="transform-box:fill-box;rotate:225deg;">way +1 0° 225° </text>
    
    <line title="240" x1="323" y1="422" x2="246" y2="289" stroke="#900" stroke-width="0.38"></line>
    <text x="246" y="289" style="transform-box:fill-box;rotate:240deg;">way +1 0° 240° </text>
    
    <line title="255" x1="323" y1="422" x2="283" y2="274" stroke="#900" stroke-width="0.38"></line>
    <text x="283" y="274" style="transform-box:fill-box;rotate:255deg;">way +1 0° 255° </text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ps61hued/)

For this purpose I generated a demo SVG with some line and text on different angles, as you can see the text is not well aligned except the 90degrees (that correctly aligns, obviously, on the text baseline). Also I tried to flip the text at 210 degrees with the "transform:scale(-1,-1);" getting unexpected result.

Despite I tried  many combination of attribute "alignment-baseline" and "text-anchor" I get worst results, how could I get texts aligned correctly?

Comment: I would draw all the lines and the text as you draw the first ones. Next I would wrap both the line and the text in a group and rotate the group `<g transform="rotate(15 323 422)">`. This means that I rotate the group 15 deg around the point x: 323 y:422 - the same point as the center of the circle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by **enxaneta** you could take advantage of SVG's transform function [`rotate(angle x y)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform#rotate) as it allows to specify a transform origin point as 2. and 3. argument.

Here's a little JS helper converting your css transformations to attributes:

```
let texts = document.querySelectorAll('text');
texts.forEach(text => {
  let angle = text.style.rotate ? parseFloat(text.style.rotate) : 0;
  // change rotation and text alignment for angles >90° 
  if(angle>=90){
    angle -=180;
    text.setAttribute('text-anchor', `end`)
  }
  let [x, y] = [+text.getAttribute('x'), +text.getAttribute('y')];
  // set svg transform attribute
  text.setAttribute('transform', `rotate(${angle} ${x} ${y})`)
  text.style.removeProperty('transform-box')
  text.style.removeProperty('rotate')
})
```

Quite likely, you're dynamically generating your diagram - so you can just adapt your script to replace the current transformation properties whil.

```js
let texts = document.querySelectorAll('text');
texts.forEach(text => {
  let angle = text.style.rotate ? parseFloat(text.style.rotate) : 0;
  // change rotation and text alignment for angles >90° 
  if(angle>=90){
    angle -=180;
    text.setAttribute('text-anchor', `end`)
  }
  let [x, y] = [+text.getAttribute('x'), +text.getAttribute('y')];
  // set svg transform attribute
  text.setAttribute('transform', `rotate(${angle} ${x} ${y})`)
  text.style.removeProperty('transform-box')
  text.style.removeProperty('rotate')
})
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 800 800" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <circle cx="323" cy="422" r="153" fill="none" stroke="#900" stroke-width="0.38" />
        <circle cx="323" cy="422" r="228" fill="none" stroke="#900" stroke-width="0.38" />
        <g id="E.3011.40-debug" class="units" font-size="10.0" fill="#000">
            <line title="0" x1="323" y1="422" x2="477" y2="422" stroke="#900" stroke-width="0.38"></line>
            <text x="477" y="422" style="">way +1 0° 0° </text>

            <line title="15" x1="323" y1="422" x2="472" y2="462" stroke="#900" stroke-width="0.38"></line>
            <text x="472" y="462" style="transform-box:fill-box;rotate:15deg;">way +1 0° 15° </text>

            <line title="30" x1="323" y1="422" x2="456" y2="499" stroke="#900" stroke-width="0.38"></line>
            <text x="456" y="499" style="transform-box:fill-box;rotate:30deg;">way +1 0° 30° </text>

            <line title="45" x1="323" y1="422" x2="432" y2="531" stroke="#900" stroke-width="0.38"></line>
            <text x="432" y="531" style="transform-box:fill-box;rotate:45deg;">way +1 0° 45° </text>

            <line title="60" x1="323" y1="422" x2="400" y2="555" stroke="#900" stroke-width="0.38"></line>
            <text x="400" y="555" style="transform-box:fill-box;rotate:60deg;">way +1 0° 60° </text>

            <line title="75" x1="323" y1="422" x2="363" y2="571" stroke="#900" stroke-width="0.38"></line>
            <text x="363" y="571" style="transform-box:fill-box;rotate:75deg;">way +1 0° 75° </text>

            <line title="90" x1="323" y1="422" x2="323" y2="576" stroke="#900" stroke-width="0.38"></line>
            <text x="323" y="576" style="transform-box:fill-box;rotate:90deg;">way +1 0° 90° </text>

            <line title="105" x1="323" y1="422" x2="283" y2="571" stroke="#900" stroke-width="0.38"></line>
            <text x="283" y="571" style="transform-box:fill-box;rotate:105deg;">way +1 0° 105° </text>

            <line title="120" x1="323" y1="422" x2="246" y2="555" stroke="#900" stroke-width="0.38"></line>
            <text x="246" y="555" style="transform-box:fill-box;rotate:120deg;">way +1 0° 120° </text>

            <line title="135" x1="323" y1="422" x2="215" y2="531" stroke="#900" stroke-width="0.38"></line>
            <text x="215" y="531" style="transform-box:fill-box;rotate:135deg;">way +1 0° 135° </text>

            <line title="150" x1="323" y1="422" x2="190" y2="499" stroke="#900" stroke-width="0.38"></line>
            <text x="190" y="499" style="transform-box:fill-box;rotate:150deg;">way +1 0° 150° </text>

            <line title="165" x1="323" y1="422" x2="175" y2="462" stroke="#900" stroke-width="0.38"></line>
            <text x="175" y="462" style="transform-box:fill-box;rotate:165deg;">way +1 0° 165° </text>

            <line title="180" x1="323" y1="422" x2="170" y2="422" stroke="#900" stroke-width="0.38"></line>
            <text x="170" y="422" style="transform-box:fill-box;rotate:180deg;">way +1 0° 180° </text>

            <line title="195" x1="323" y1="422" x2="175" y2="383" stroke="#900" stroke-width="0.38"></line>
            <text x="175" y="383" style="transform-box:fill-box;rotate:195deg;">way +1 0° 195° </text>

            <line title="210" x1="323" y1="422" x2="190" y2="346" stroke="#900" stroke-width="1"></line>
            <text x="190" y="346" style="transform-box:fill-box;rotate:210deg;transform:scale(-1,-1);">way +1 0° 210°
            </text>

            <line title="225" x1="323" y1="422" x2="215" y2="314" stroke="#900" stroke-width="0.38"></line>
            <text x="215" y="314" style="transform-box:fill-box;rotate:225deg;">way +1 0° 225° </text>

            <line title="240" x1="323" y1="422" x2="246" y2="289" stroke="#900" stroke-width="0.38"></line>
            <text x="246" y="289" style="transform-box:fill-box;rotate:240deg;">way +1 0° 240° </text>

            <line title="255" x1="323" y1="422" x2="283" y2="274" stroke="#900" stroke-width="0.38"></line>
            <text x="283" y="274" style="transform-box:fill-box;rotate:255deg;">way +1 0° 255° </text>
        </g>
    </svg>
```

Another benefit of using SVG's `rotate()` function is it's support even in less capable svg applications:
Many graphic editors have only limited CSS capabilities - especially with regards to transform properties like `transform-box` or `transform-origin`.

If you prefer to use CSS transforms you can emulate SVG's pivot point rotation by applying two `translate()` values:

```
text.style.transform = `translate(${x}px, ${y}px) rotate(${angle}deg) translate(${-x}px, ${-y}px)`;
```

```js
let texts = document.querySelectorAll('text');
texts.forEach(text => {
  let angle = text.style.rotate ? parseFloat(text.style.rotate) : 0;
  let [x, y] = [+text.getAttribute('x'), +text.getAttribute('y')];

  // change rotation and text alignment for angles >90° 
  if (angle >= 90) {
    angle -= 180;
    text.setAttribute('text-anchor', `end`)
  }

  // use css transform
  text.style.transform = `translate(${x}px, ${y}px) rotate(${angle}deg) translate(${-x}px, ${-y}px)`;

  text.style.removeProperty('transform-box')
  text.style.removeProperty('rotate')

})
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 800 800" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <circle cx="323" cy="422" r="153" fill="none" stroke="#900" stroke-width="0.38" />
        <circle cx="323" cy="422" r="228" fill="none" stroke="#900" stroke-width="0.38" />
        <g id="E.3011.40-debug" class="units" font-size="10.0" fill="#000">
            <line title="0" x1="323" y1="422" x2="477" y2="422" stroke="#900" stroke-width="0.38"></line>
            <text x="477" y="422" style="">way +1 0° 0° </text>

            <line title="15" x1="323" y1="422" x2="472" y2="462" stroke="#900" stroke-width="0.38"></line>
            <text x="472" y="462" style="transform-box:fill-box;rotate:15deg;">way +1 0° 15° </text>

            <line title="30" x1="323" y1="422" x2="456" y2="499" stroke="#900" stroke-width="0.38"></line>
            <text x="456" y="499" style="transform-box:fill-box;rotate:30deg;">way +1 0° 30° </text>

            <line title="45" x1="323" y1="422" x2="432" y2="531" stroke="#900" stroke-width="0.38"></line>
            <text x="432" y="531" style="transform-box:fill-box;rotate:45deg;">way +1 0° 45° </text>

            <line title="60" x1="323" y1="422" x2="400" y2="555" stroke="#900" stroke-width="0.38"></line>
            <text x="400" y="555" style="transform-box:fill-box;rotate:60deg;">way +1 0° 60° </text>

            <line title="75" x1="323" y1="422" x2="363" y2="571" stroke="#900" stroke-width="0.38"></line>
            <text x="363" y="571" style="transform-box:fill-box;rotate:75deg;">way +1 0° 75° </text>

            <line title="90" x1="323" y1="422" x2="323" y2="576" stroke="#900" stroke-width="0.38"></line>
            <text x="323" y="576" style="transform-box:fill-box;rotate:90deg;">way +1 0° 90° </text>

            <line title="105" x1="323" y1="422" x2="283" y2="571" stroke="#900" stroke-width="0.38"></line>
            <text x="283" y="571" style="transform-box:fill-box;rotate:105deg;">way +1 0° 105° </text>

            <line title="120" x1="323" y1="422" x2="246" y2="555" stroke="#900" stroke-width="0.38"></line>
            <text x="246" y="555" style="transform-box:fill-box;rotate:120deg;">way +1 0° 120° </text>

            <line title="135" x1="323" y1="422" x2="215" y2="531" stroke="#900" stroke-width="0.38"></line>
            <text x="215" y="531" style="transform-box:fill-box;rotate:135deg;">way +1 0° 135° </text>

            <line title="150" x1="323" y1="422" x2="190" y2="499" stroke="#900" stroke-width="0.38"></line>
            <text x="190" y="499" style="transform-box:fill-box;rotate:150deg;">way +1 0° 150° </text>

            <line title="165" x1="323" y1="422" x2="175" y2="462" stroke="#900" stroke-width="0.38"></line>
            <text x="175" y="462" style="transform-box:fill-box;rotate:165deg;">way +1 0° 165° </text>

            <line title="180" x1="323" y1="422" x2="170" y2="422" stroke="#900" stroke-width="0.38"></line>
            <text x="170" y="422" style="transform-box:fill-box;rotate:180deg;">way +1 0° 180° </text>

            <line title="195" x1="323" y1="422" x2="175" y2="383" stroke="#900" stroke-width="0.38"></line>
            <text x="175" y="383" style="transform-box:fill-box;rotate:195deg;">way +1 0° 195° </text>

            <line title="210" x1="323" y1="422" x2="190" y2="346" stroke="#900" stroke-width="1"></line>
            <text x="190" y="346" style="transform-box:fill-box;rotate:210deg;transform:scale(-1,-1);">way +1 0° 210°
            </text>

            <line title="225" x1="323" y1="422" x2="215" y2="314" stroke="#900" stroke-width="0.38"></line>
            <text x="215" y="314" style="transform-box:fill-box;rotate:225deg;">way +1 0° 225° </text>

            <line title="240" x1="323" y1="422" x2="246" y2="289" stroke="#900" stroke-width="0.38"></line>
            <text x="246" y="289" style="transform-box:fill-box;rotate:240deg;">way +1 0° 240° </text>

            <line title="255" x1="323" y1="422" x2="283" y2="274" stroke="#900" stroke-width="0.38"></line>
            <text x="283" y="274" style="transform-box:fill-box;rotate:255deg;">way +1 0° 255° </text>
        </g>
    </svg>
```

Comment: Yes they are both the definitive solution, so grateful, now my SVG looks so precise!  I will use the first one (also suggested by *enxaneta*) to generate less code, anyway I'm still struggling to flip the text upside for degrees from 105 to 255, any suggestion?

Comment: You can decrease angles>=90 by 180° and change text alignment via `text-anchor="end"`. See updated snippet.

Comment: thank you **herrstrietzel** again, it works!